# Where can I find historic ratios by industry?

Tags: historical-data, ratio

Where can I find 3-5 year historical data showing average or leading financial ratios by industry. For example, in industries like wireless, telecom,or biotech.

The ratios I'm referring to are these metrics:

1. P/E Ratio
2. Market to book Ratio
3. Quick Ratio
4. Current Ratio
5. Debt to Equity
6. Return on Assets
7. Return on Equity
8. Inventory Turnover
9. Asset Turnover

I can usually find them for individual firms or calculate them on the 10-K statements; however, I have not found a reliable source on the web to compare to industry averages.

I read through this post but it seems like it only has current data:

[Where can I obtain historic ratios for a sector?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/where-can-i-obtain-historic-ratios-for-a-sector)

Are there pay services perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to find data on a specific industry/market sector, a good option is IBISworld reports. You can find their site [here](http://www.ibisworld.com/industry/home.aspx).

You can find reports on almost any major US sector. The reports include historical data as well as financial ratios.

In college projects, they were very useful for getting benchmark data to compare an individual business against an industry as a whole.